# Wireshark physical packet

Tags: networking, network-protocols

How does wireshark interpret physical packets?
As far as I know, all packets look to be the same, so how does it decode them to pass to next higher protocol?

Answer (score 1):

When it's used to capture live traffic it knows the type of the interface and therefore the L2 encapsulation of packets, and when it reads a pcap file, the file has a field in the header indicating network type.

Comment: One more query... Dissector_tables is used to store the sub dissectors for a particular dissector. So is this Dissector table local to each to Dissector or what kind of mapping is there? M a beginer

Answer (score 1):

There are probably a number of different mechanisms.  You can download the dissectors and study the source to find out the various methods.

I wrote a dissector for a network sniffer and ported it to Ethereal and then Wireshark (or maybe someone else ported it; I don't remember).  But the basic logic is that the dissector gets added to the list of possible dissectors.  Wireshark calls a dissector and it decodes the packet if it can.  If not, it calls the next one in the chain.

In the code I wrote, I simply analyzed the packet (UDP in my situation) to determine if it fit the profile of the desired packet using checksums and known data in the packet.  If it decided it was the packet I was interested in I just extracted the various pieces of interesting data from the packet.  The function `tvb_get_ptr` returns a pointer to the start of the data.

Comment: tell me one more thing... i am reading about this protocol tree... i think this is nothing but the tree that wireshark forms after calling disectors followed by sub dissectors till the end. so there is one independent tree per dissector. am i correct?

Comment: @user420878, I believe that is correct, but my memory on it is very vague.  I just checked the revisions and see that it was over 7 years ago that I ported it to Ethereal, so I don't remember a lot of the details.